# Has anyone built a custom RabbitMQ exchange which creates queues for unbound routing keys?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I'd like to setup an Alternate Exchange which catches all messages with routing keys that aren't bound to any queues. I'd also like the exchange to then create a new queue bound to the new routing key and then republish the message there. For example, if two messages arrive with routing keys 'a' and 'b' to exchange ex_1, and it has no matching queues, the message will automatically be forwarded to the alternate exchange ex_1_ae. I'd like to then have two queues dynamically created for those messages and any future ones with those routing keys and bound to exchange ex_1. If another message comes along later with a routing key of 'c' I'd like yet another queue automatically created and bound to ex_1. Has anyone built such a custom exchange and / or could point me in the direction of the source?

I've started trying to write a custom exchange myself but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I'd also upvote an answer that provides a simple custom exchange that I could use as a base to create the custom exchange I want. I've looked at the community exchanges in RabbitMQ's GitHub account but these all seem very complicated. I tried using https://github.com/thecederick/rabbitmq-arguments-to-headers-exchange as a starting point but at this stage I'm having trouble getting it to work so I'm trying to find another example or in the best case a custom exchange that does exactly what I want.

I'm trying to implement this because I need to have an isolated subscriber agent for each individual routing key. I realise that when the agent subscribes with a particular routing key a queue can be dynamically created, but in my scenario the messages themselves will trigger the creation of the subscriber and by the time it starts up multiple messages with it's routing key may have already been encountered. This is why I need the queues dynamically created when the first novel message arrives at the exchange, not when the subscriber agent starts running. When the subscriber does start running, there will already be a queue waiting for it with one or more pending messages.

Comment: I didn't get why you need a custom exchange. you can just configure an exchange the bind a queue where you will have all your un-routed messages.

Comment: @Gabriele +1 for the comment, my thoughts exactly

Comment: @Gabriele I need a queue created dynamically *per* routing key. I.e. If two messages arrive with routing keys 'a' and 'b' I want two queues added to the initial exchange automatically which then handle those messages, plus any future ones with those keys. If a then another message arrive with a routing key of 'C', I need a third queue created automatically. I could write a subscriber to a single alternate queue, in a language of my choice, which then does this queue creation but then I have to manage that subscriber. Id prefer to just create a custom exchange that does this.

Comment: I've updated the question to add this extra clarity

Comment: Instead of creating custom exchange you can create a consumer, that will subscribe to alternate exchange sink queue, create queues for each routing key and bind them to original exchange (and then republish messages).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DaniilFedotov, I'm actually working on this at the moment to get something shipped. Ultimately though I would still like the custom exchange. I feel that it would be one less component to worry about since this 'management consumer' has to be highly available etc and so requires more maintenance than something built into the exchange.